# Доступ к массиву из другого класса

Tags: c#, массивы

Здравствуйте, только начала изучать C#, столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Нужно инициализировать массив и его размер с клавиатуры, а потом открыть доступ к нему и его элементам для другого класса.

Нерабочий код:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Massive instance = new Massive();
        Console.WriteLine("Размер массива: ");
        instance.Size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(instance.Size);

        instance.Input();
        instance.Output();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Massive
{
    int i;
    int size = 0;
    int []mass = new int[size]; //инициализатор поля не может обращаться к нестатическому полю 

    public int Size
    {
        set
        {
            size = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return size;
        }
    }

    public void Input()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите элемент массива: ");
            mass[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    public void Output()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" "+mass[i]);
        }
    }

}

class Massive2 : Massive
{
    //доступ к массиву и его элементам с класса Massive
}
}
```

**Обновлённый код**

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

        namespace ConsoleApplication1
        {
        class MainClass
        {
        static void Main()
        {
        Massive instance = new Massive();
        Console.WriteLine("Размер массива: ");
        instance.Size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(instance.Size);

        instance.Input();
        instance.Output();

        Massive2 instance2 = new Massive2();
        Console.WriteLine();
        instance2.Method();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


class Massive
{
    int[] mass = null;
    int i;

    public int Size
    {
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
                mass = new int[value];
            else
                mass = null;
        }
        get
        {
            return (mass != null) ? mass.Length : 0;
        }
    }

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get { return mass[index]; } //ошибка здесь
        set { mass[index] = value; }
    }

    public void Input()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите элемент массива: ");
            mass[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
    public void Output()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" " + mass[i]);
        }
    }


}
class Massive2 : Massive
{
    public void Method()
    {
        //доступ к массиву и его элементам с класса Massive
        int test = this[4];
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: так, `instance2` - это совсем другой объект, у которого `Size` - ноль, а `mass` - null. Добавьте строчку `instance2.Size = 5;` перед `instance2.Method();`

Answer (score 3):

```
class Massive
{
  int i;
  int size = 0;
  int []mass = null; 

  public int Size
  {
    set
    {
      size = value;
      // check for size > 0
      mass = new int[size];
    }
    get
    {
      return size;
    }
  }

  public int this[int index]
  {
    get { return mass[index]; }
    set { mass[index] = value } 
  }
  ...
```

Можно обойтись без поля `size`, а использовать сам массив для получения его длины:

```
class Massive
{
  int []mass = null; 

  public int Size
  {
    set
    {
      if (value > 0)
        mass = new int[value];
      else
        mass = null;
    }
    get
    {
      return (mass != null)? mass.Length : 0;
    }
  }

  public int this[int index]
  {
    get { return mass[index]; }
    set { mass[index] = value } 
  }

  public void Input()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Введите элемент массива: ");
      mass[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
  }
  ...
```

**Update**

```
static void Main()
{
  Massive2 instance2 = new Massive2();
  Console.WriteLine("Размер массива: ");
  instance2.Size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine(instance2.Size);

  instance2.Input();
  instance2.Output();

  instance2.Method();

  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как теперь получить доступ к какому-то элементу mass в классе Massive2 : Massive ? 
Пробую int x  = this.mass[4]; но получаю ошибку "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: @mwchqq `int x = this[4];`, ну и убедитесь, что до этого Вы назначили `Size` не меньше пяти

Comment: не могу понять почему не получается, Size не меньше пяти.
http://i.imgur.com/j5MXZAT.png

Comment: @mwchqq По картинке нельзя сказать. Очевидно, что член класса `mass` - `null`. Добавьте полный код (на данный момент) в вопрос. Ошибка должна быть простой.

Comment: @mwchqq так, `instance2` - это совсем другой объект, у которого `Size` - ноль, а `mass` - null. Добавьте строчку `instance2.Size = 5;` перед `instance2.Method();`

Comment: а как тогда передать значения Size и mass объекта instance объекту instance2?

Comment: @mwchqq а зачем? Создавайте сразу `Massive2`. Объясните, чего Вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53478/discussion-between-mwchqq-and-igor).

Comment: @mwchqq добавил пример `Main`, который может Вам подойти